# What header variables do I need to use to extract a tar file

Tags: c, binaryfiles, tar

I intend to do a C program that extracts a `.tar` archive. I'm currently using `Debian` from my Windows Terminal, and code using the Windows Version of `Visual Studio Code`.

As far as I know, tar files contain a `header` block (of 512 bytes) and the block with all the `content` of the certain file (also of 512 bytes).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)), I found out that the `header` contains loads of variables that contain the name of the certain file, its mode, the name of the user that archived the tar file, and so on.

Based on what Wikipedia has taught me, I'm using two structs: one for the header of the certain file, and one for its content (...)

```
typedef struct tarHeaderBody {
    char fname[100];
    char file_mode[8];
    char owner_numeric_userid[8];
    char group_numeric_userid[8];
    char file_size[12];
    char last_modification_time[12];
    char checksum[8];
    char link_indicator;
    char linkedfname[100];
    char severalFields[156];
    char typeFlag;
    char sameField[100];
    char ustarIndicator[6];
    char ustartVer[2];
    char ownerUserName[32];
    char ownerGroupName[32];
    char deviceMajorNo[8];
    char deviceMinorNo[8];
    char fnameprefix[155];
} tarHeader;

typedef struct tarContentBody {
    char content[512];
} tarContent;
```

(...) declared in the main function as:

```
tarHeader t;
tarContent tContent;
```

I'm using `fopen()` and `fread()` using the first struct to read the contents of the header:

```
FILE *f = fopen("output.tar", "rb")
fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, f);
```

The file is read correctly. I'm also trying to output every variable from the struct, and starting from `t.severalFields`, variables are outputted "weird". Also, the content of the archived text file is outputted somewhere in these header variables.

I'm pretty sure the issue is with the organizing of the header variables, especially with the `t.severalFields` variable, as I should declare more variables that contain the info from there. The problem is, I don't find any website or source of information that may help me in doing so. I don't know what variables or info `t.severalFields' contains.

Also, named the variable `severalFields` because in the first row from the third table from the Wikipedia link mentioned above, there lays written:

> 0 156 (Several fields, same as in the old format)

meaning that it is a variable with a size of 156 bytes.

So, my final question is: what variables should my `tarHeaderBody` struct contain? Do I need all of them if I want to extract the files? Or are the name of the file and its content (which doesn't lay in the header) enough? Thank you so much.

Also, if you need more snippets of the code, I can provide them to you.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually? There are lots of libraries out there to read tar files.

Comment: @klutt Received an assignment to develop a program that makes it manually

Comment: What format are you required to implement?  Because there is no standard for tar file formats any more.  GNU effectively embraced, extended, and extinguished the tar file standard.  POSIX [***had*** a `tar` standard utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/tar.html).  The [latest version of the POSIX standard no longer has a `tar` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Comment: @AndrewHenle "your programs must be compatible with the original GNU tar", I think that's what you're talking about

Comment: @AndrewHenle They just renamed it `pax`.

Comment: When I wrote a tar reader many moons ago, IIRC it just read a field at a time, did any parsing needed, and then saved its value in a struct. No mucking about with trying to match up struct fields with the header blocks.

Comment: @Shawn *They just renamed it `pax`.*  First, they ***had*** to rename it.  GNU `tar` so polluted the space that there was no way to standardize "tar" file formats any longer without invalidating someone's implementation(s). So yeah, GNU extinguished `tar` as a standard utility. [`pax` is also a lot more complex than `tar`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html), so it's not just a forced rename of the same utility.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in your structure, because, as you have noted, it shouldn't be longer than 512 bytes.

```
typedef struct tarHeaderBody {
    char fname[100];
    char file_mode[8];
    char owner_numeric_userid[8];
    char group_numeric_userid[8];
    char file_size[12];
    char last_modification_time[12];
    char checksum[8];
    char link_indicator;
    char linkedfname[100];
    char severalFields[156];
    char typeFlag;
    char sameField[100];
    char ustarIndicator[6];
    char ustartVer[2];
    char ownerUserName[32];
    char ownerGroupName[32];
    char deviceMajorNo[8];
    char deviceMinorNo[8];
    char fnameprefix[155];
} tarHeader;
```

You have specified an extra 156 bytes. From [gnu.org Basic Tar Format](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html);

> The header block is defined in C as follows. In the GNU tar distribution, this is part of file ‘src/tar.h’:

```
/* tar Header Block, from POSIX 1003.1-1990.  */

/* POSIX header.  */

struct posix_header
{                              /* byte offset */
  char name[100];               /*   0 */
  char mode[8];                 /* 100 */
  char uid[8];                  /* 108 */
  char gid[8];                  /* 116 */
  char size[12];                /* 124 */
  char mtime[12];               /* 136 */
  char chksum[8];               /* 148 */
  char typeflag;                /* 156 */
  char linkname[100];           /* 157 */
  char magic[6];                /* 257 */
  char version[2];              /* 263 */
  char uname[32];               /* 265 */
  char gname[32];               /* 297 */
  char devmajor[8];             /* 329 */
  char devminor[8];             /* 337 */
  char prefix[155];             /* 345 */
                                /* 500 */
};
```

Note the absence of `severalFields` from before `typeFlag`.

> I'm pretty sure the issue is with the organizing of the header
> variables, especially with the `t.severalFields` variable, as I should
> declare more variables that contain the info from there. The problem
> is, I don't find any website or source of information that may help me
> in doing so. I don't know what variables or info `t.severalFields'
> contains.
>
> Also, named the variable `severalFields` because in the first row from
> the third table from the Wikipedia link mentioned above, there lays
> written:
>
> > 0   156 (Several fields, same as in the old format)
>
> meaning that it is a variable with a size of 156 bytes.

That section of the document refers to an entirely new structure (the POSIX header) which extends the old one (the format).

> "your programs must be compatible with the original GNU tar"

Based on this requirement, you are free to choose amongst formats. The easiest, I feel, is the original, since it is the simplest (this is best if your assignment is simply to extract a few files or folders).

> So, my final question is: what variables should my `tarHeaderBody` struct contain?

Nothing; you can get rid of it.

> are the name of the file and its content (which doesn't lay in the header) enough?

For basic file extraction, yes.

> I intend to do a C program that extracts a `.tar` archive. I'm currently using `Debian` from my Windows Terminal, and code using the Windows Version of `Visual Studio Code`.

A noble journey to embark on. At the very least, you'll learn about file archives (if only the very basics!) and possibly disk I/O.

> Received an assignment to develop a program that makes it manually

So, the due date is probably long past, but I hope that my post somehow helps.

Good luck with your studies!